# How I can add a cflag in cmake Android Studio?

Tags: android-ndk, cmake

How I can add -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 in Cmake config file. I'm trying to add as cflag in build.gradle but it not work.

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
            cFlags "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"
            arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

In the CMakeLists.txt file, I do something like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D__ANDROID__ -DANDROID -DCUSTOM_FLAG")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES=1 -DIOAPI_NO_64 -DUSE_FILE32API ")
```

However, you can use gradle too, but `externalNativeBuild` needs to be under `defaultConfig` or `release` or `debug` (a build flavor) for [cmake options](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions:cFlags) to pass the flags.

For Example:

```js
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "..."
 
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    // here, arguments, cppFlags, cFlags, ..  all work
                    arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15',
                            '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static',
                            '-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions'
                }
            }
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                // only 'path' variable is valid here
                path '../../gameSource/CMakeLists.txt'
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
               // .. release flavor
            }
            debug {
                //... debug flavor
            }
        }
    }
```