# Using Gradle to compile c++ for android - compiles in Visual Studio but not in Gradle?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, gradle

I am trying to port my basic sdl game over onto android, but I've been stuck for a while now on using gradle. While I can compile an APK using a very basic main.cpp, as soon as I start coding as I normally would I get all sorts of errors that simply don't crop up in the visual studio compiler. For example, "nullptr not defined in this scope", for each causes not being acceptable, and lots of warnings saying bits of code are only available in -stdC++11. The error feed I could mostly rewrite my code around, but I'd much rather be able to have gradle compile using the same rules the VS compiler does... What am I doing wrong?
Thanks 
Will

edit:
previous question is similar but I am not using android studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable C++11 for Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667374/how-to-enable-c11-for-android-studio)

Comment: I have several projects that compile on XCode, Android Studio and Visual Studio.  [This is how I setup Gradle/CMake to compile on Android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294140/how-i-can-add-a-cflag-in-cmake-android-studio/44295150#44295150)  If you are just starting out, make sure to use CMake projects and not Android.mk.  They are musch, much faster